# Trying to install steam

Tags: steam

I've been trying to install steam all day and I've been encountering all kinds of problems, but I'd like a little bit of help with this specific one:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you please copy/paste the error message instead of a screenshot ? Thanks :).

Comment: sure, here
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Run the command `sudo apt-get install libudev1:i386` and post the output here http://paste.ubuntu.com/. After that, give us the link.

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libudev1:i386 : Depends: libcgmanager0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Use http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13330396/

Comment: Same procedure as before, run `sudo apt-get install libcgmanager0:i386`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13330435/

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libcgmanager0`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13330515/

Comment: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install libcgmanager0:i386; apt-cache policy libcgmanager0:i386 libcgmanager0`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13330640/

Comment: `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13330676/

Comment: `apt-get download libcgmanager0:i386; sudo dpkg -i --force-all libcgmanager0*i386.deb`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13330703/

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libcgmanager0:i386=0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13330731/

Comment: `wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cgmanager/libcgmanager0_0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1_i386.deb; sudo dpkg -i libcgmanager0_0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1_i386.deb`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13330764/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake ... `wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cgmanager/libcgmanager0_0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1_i386.deb ; sudo dpkg -i libcgmanager0_0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1_i386.deb`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13330800/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13330854/

Comment: Funny =) http://paste.ubuntu.com/13330869/ Use this.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13330905/

Comment: `sudo dpkg -im --force-all libcgmanager0_0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1_i386.deb`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13330946/

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i --force-all libcgmanager0_0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1_i386.deb`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13330984/

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libudev1:i386`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13331066/

Comment: aww... I will wait for @A.B. to come back...

Comment: are we getting anywhere? xd

Comment: `apt-cache policy libcgmanager0:i386 libcgmanager0`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13331153/

Comment: have you changed anything in the APT configuration?

Comment: `apt-cache policy libc6:i386 libc6`

Comment: I don't know what the apt configuration in the first place xd

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13331224/

Comment: `apt-get download libc6:i386; sudo dpkg -i --force-all libc6*i386.deb`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13331371/

Comment: oh wait
http://paste.ubuntu.com/13331397/

Comment: `apt-cache policy libc6:i386 libc6`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13331434/

Comment: `apt-cache policy libgcc1`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13331476/

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgcc1`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13331541/

Comment: I have to go, I'm back in 30 minutes

Comment: Run the next command, but **don't** press `Y`. `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13332050/

Comment: Ok, `sudo apt-get install steam`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13332126/

Comment: `sudo apt-get check`

Comment: Great, answer added, please accept with a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer.  **;)**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31999/discussion-on-question-by-ig0killamatricriikz-trying-to-install-steam).

Answer (score 5):

### Conclusion

More details see the next section

- It is important to consider the output of the commands like `apt-cache package_name`.
- `sudo dpkg -i --force-all deb_file` is a great help when you need to force the installation of a package by any means
- The reinstallation of a package sometimes can solve dependency problems that actually are no dependency problems.

---

### Details

I can not determine what the exact cause of the problem was. The following output appears to have been the main problem. You can see that the installation candidate for `libcgmanager0:i386` is version `0.24-0ubuntu7.5`. But `libcgmanager0` and `libcgmanager0:i386` have to be exactly the same version.

```
% apt-cache policy libcgmanager0:i386 libcgmanager0
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libudev1 : Depends: libcgmanager0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
libcgmanager0:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.24-0ubuntu7.5
  Version table:
     0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
     0.24-0ubuntu7.5 0
        500 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
     0.24-0ubuntu7.1 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
     0.24-0ubuntu5 0
        500 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
libcgmanager0:
  Installed: 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.24-0ubuntu7.5 0
        500 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     0.24-0ubuntu7.1 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     0.24-0ubuntu5 0
        500 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

For this reason we downloaded the package and manually forced the installation.

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cgmanager/libcgmanager0_0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libcgmanager0_0.39-2ubunt‌​u2~ubuntu14.04.1_i386.deb
```

---

Whether the next steps were still necessary, I can not say exactly. I simply just list them ...

```
apt-get download libc6:i386
sudo dpkg -i --force-all libc6*i386.deb
```

And now we had

```
(Reading database ... 196730 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libc6_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libc6:i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) over (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
dpkg: libc6:i386: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
 libc6:i386 depends on libgcc1.

Setting up libc6:i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
ig0killahr79@ig0killahr79-Inspiron-3537:~$ apt-get download libc6:i386; sudo dpkg -i --force-all libc6*i386.deb
(Reading database ... 196730 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libc6_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libc6:i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) over (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
dpkg: libc6:i386: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
 libc6:i386 depends on libgcc1.

Setting up libc6:i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
```

Solved with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgcc1
```

---

After a test with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

we got this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Looks great and finally

```
% sudo apt-get install steam:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
steam:i386 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Looks like I only needed to install the correct version of `libcgmanager0` (as you pointed out :) ). Use `gdebi` if you don't want to mess with dependencies manually.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386
sudo apt-get install steam
```

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Comment: I have updated my answer, please try again.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386 : Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Please try the new updated answer :)

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing steam from software-center, and it works or download it from http://store.steampowered.com, and it might work fine this way

Comment: Why is the installation from Software Center different?

Comment: There is a more benefit from the producer, and all most the same but I would use this one.